# For each row in CSV add rows from second CSV

Tags: python

I need to achieve a simple task: For all rows in one CSV, I need to iterate through another CSV and add those values.

Assume File1.csv has the following values:
A, B 
X, Y

And File2.csv has the following values: 
1, 2

My result could be: 
A-1-B 
A-2-B 
X-1-Y 
X-2-Y

No code yet. I've looked at various answers here and nothing approximates.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('File1.csv') as f1, open('File2.csv') as f2:
    xs = f2.read().strip().split(', ')
    for line in f1.readlines():
        a, b = line.strip().split(', ')
        for x in xs:
            print(a, x, b, sep='-')
```

If your csv files have more complex quoting or escape characters, use the `csv` module instead of a plain `open`, it's more robust.

If the files are huge, you might want to stream them instead of reading them all into memory at once.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `.trim()` -- Did you mean `.strip()` by any chance?

Comment: @hqkhan yes, that's what I get for not testing my code.

Comment: This happens: 

`File "<input>", line 7` 
    `print(a, x, b, sep='-')`
      `                ^`
`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Line breaks in comments would certainly be nice. The error happened in the reference to "sep"

Comment: Also errors "ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack"

Comment: @Jonathan if you're still using the outdated Python 2, that should really be in the tags. Either add `from __future__ import print_function` to the top of the file, or use Python 3.